# ModelSerializer 'TypeError: "ReturnList" is not callable' with many=True

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to serialize a queryset from the model ObjectTag and then use it to serialize a reverse generic relationship in another model. However, this simple ModelSerializer is giving me problems when using many=True and a queryset or when serializing one instance.

I have a model serializer as follows:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from . import models

class ObjectTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.ObjectTag
        fields = ('tag_content_type', 'object_id', 'object_content_type')
```

And the model is defined as follow:

```
class ObjectTag(models.Model):
    """
    Many to many to attach tags to objects.
    """
    object_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        related_name="object_object_tag" # necessary to avoid clash in ContentType
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('object_content_type', 'object_id')

    tag_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        limit_choices_to={
            "model__in": tags.TagManager.tag_class_names,
            "app_label": tags.TagManager.app_label
        },
        related_name="tag_object_tag" # necessary to avoid clash in ContentType
    )
    tag_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_tag = GenericForeignKey('tag_content_type', 'tag_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('tag_id', 'tag_content_type', 'object_id', 'object_content_type'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return u'object tag: {tag_type}: {tag} \u21D2 {obj}'.format(
            tag_type=self.content_tag._meta.verbose_name,
            tag=self.content_tag,
            obj=self.content_object,
        )
```

When I try to serialize a queryset with many=True from the model ObjectTag, I get the following error:

```
from .models import ObjectTag
from .serializers import ObjectTagSerializer
ot = ObjectTag.objects.filter(object_id=14691)
ObjectTagSerializer(ot, many=True, read_only=True).data()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ReturnList' object is not callable
```

And when serializing one instance, I get the following:

```
ObjectTagSerializer(ot[0], read_only=True).data()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ReturnDict' object is not callable
```

I am using DRF 3.3.2 and Django 1.8 and Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the brackets from '.data()' and it should work. ReturnDict and ReturnList are the return types of the Serializers, and they are not callables